# What does it mean to "run an object" in Javascript?

Tags: typescript

In the code below, the content of if block is just "animal", which is an object of type Fish | Bird | Human. So it seems it runs object "animal". What does it mean to "run" animal?

```
type Fish = { swim: () => void };
type Bird = { fly: () => void };
type Human = { swim?: () => void; fly?: () => void };
 
function move(animal: Fish | Bird | Human) {
    if ("swim" in animal) {
        animal;
    } else {
        animal;
    }
}
```

The code compiles. If the function is invoked, it returns undefined.

Comment: Are you asking about what an [Expression statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Expression_statement) is/does?

Comment: The code as written seems quite useless; presumably the point is that you can see that TS [narrows](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) the apparent type of `animal` in each block, but you're not supposed to just *leave* it like that.  You'd write, say, `animal.swim?.()` in the first case and `animal.fly?.()` in the second.  The `animal;` is an expression statement, but since `animal` is just an object there is almost certainly no side-effect, and therefore no purpose whatsoever.  The object is evaluated and then apparently discarded.

Comment: Does that fully address the question? If so someone could write up an answer, I guess, but it seems like a strange question since you're asking for the meaning of apparently meaningless code.  if not, what's missing?

Comment: I don't have solid knowledge about javascript. I didn't know an expression can be a statement. Thanks!